# What method would you recommend for a text box , where the text stays inside bounds and decrease font size to stay inside bounds

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I need a text box that needs to allow the user to type text into the textbox and the text stays inside the textbox bounds.And if it the user type too much text it will decrease the font in order for it to fit inside the text box bounds. I don`t know which object will be able to fit this requirement.

Comment: Did you try setting the minimum font value and setting the adjust to fit to true?

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I *just* implemented this. Here's how I did it:

```
- (void)fitTextView {
    CGFloat height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 16;

    _fontSize = 96;
    _text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:_fontName size:_fontSize];

    while (height < _text.contentSize.height) {
        if (_fontSize < 20) {
            break;
        }
    
        _fontSize -= 0.5;
        _text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:_fontName size:_fontSize];
    }
    
    while (height > _text.contentSize.height) {
        if (_fontSize > 96) {
            break;
        }
        
        _fontSize += 0.5;
        _text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:_fontName size:_fontSize];
    }
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    [self fitTextView];
}
```

There's a bit of a problem with my code, though, where the text that's being typed in bounces around a bit if you type fast enough. Would love to get some feedback on how to fix that.

### Edit

A little more code.

```
_fontSize = 96; 
_fontName = @"Helvetica";

_text = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
_text.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
_text.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
_text.delegate = self;
_text.text = @"";
_text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:_fontName size:_fontSize];
_text.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];
_text.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:1];
[self.view addSubview:_text];
```

And remember to declare that your class implements the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol.

Comment: wait, may you show the code for your textview and font size. I want to make sure I get this right, I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using UITextField (as you stated its a text box.

So you can use the following

```
[yourTextField setMinimumFontSize:7.0];
[yourTextField setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
```